# Method for associating vector elements with items they represent

Tags: ruby, algorithm, data-structures, vector

Imagine an "item" structure (represented as a JSON hash)

```
{
  id: 1,
  value: 5
}
```

Now imagine I have a set of 100,000 items, and I need to perform calculations on the value associated with each.  At the end of the calculation, I update each item with the new value.

To do this quickly, I have been using GSL vector libraries, loading each value as an element of the vector.

For example, the items:

```
{ id: 1, value: 5 }
{ id: 2, value: 6 }
{ id: 3, value: 7 }
```

Becomes:

```
GSL::Vector[5, 6, 7]
```

Element 1 corresponds to item id 1, element 2 corresponds to item id 2, etc.  I then proceed to perform element-wise calculations on each element in the vector, multiplying, dividing etc.

While this works, it bothers me that I have to depend on the list of items being sorted by ID.

Is there another structure that acts like a hash (allowing me to say with certainty a particular result value corresponds to a particular item), but allows me to do fast, memory efficient element-wise operations like a vector?

I'm using Ruby and the GSL bindings, but willing to re-write this in another language if necessary.

Comment: If you have gaps between ID's probably it's better to use HashMap (Hash for ruby), I don't understand why it's a problem to assume that data is sorted by ID

Comment: I assume it worries you because you might have gaps in the id range. An associative array won't have this problem. Like varela says - use a HashMap. It will tolerate gaps in the ids.

Comment: As it is a large amount of standardized data, why not push it into a database like SQLite?
DB access operations are much optimized. Besides, Ruby has excellent DB libraries.

Comment: The issue here is that its much faster to perform operations in a vector than in a loop.  So if I need to perform a complex calculation on the value of 1 million items, its much faster to create 100, 10,000 element vectors, and perform the operations, than looping through 1 million items.  So I don't think I can use a hash map.